# Bookmark no longer valid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.5

I am working on an indent and outdent for the advanced datagrid. I have a set of functions which work when operating on the underlying data fine, but which throw "Error: Bookmark no longer valid" when operating on the selected items of the datagrid.

```
Error: Bookmark no longer valid.
    at ListCollectionViewCursor/seek()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\collections\ListCollectionView.as:2429]
    at mx.collections::HierarchicalCollectionViewCursor/get current()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\advancedgrids\src\mx\collections\HierarchicalCollectionViewCursor.as:220]
    at mx.collections::HierarchicalCollectionViewCursor/collectionChangeHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\advancedgrids\src\mx\collections\HierarchicalCollectionViewCursor.as:1152]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.collections::HierarchicalCollectionView/collectionChangeHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\advancedgrids\src\mx\collections\HierarchicalCollectionView.as:1485]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.collections::ListCollectionView/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\collections\ListCollectionView.as:1024]
    at mx.collections::ListCollectionView/handlePropertyChangeEvents()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\collections\ListCollectionView.as:1449]
    at mx.collections::ListCollectionView/listChangeHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\collections\ListCollectionView.as:1316]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.collections::XMLListAdapter/itemUpdateHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\collections\XMLListAdapter.as:623]
    at mx.collections::XMLListAdapter/itemUpdated()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\collections\XMLListAdapter.as:366]
    at mx.collections::XMLListAdapter/xmlNotification()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\collections\XMLListAdapter.as:725]
    at Function/<anonymous>()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\utils\XMLNotifier.as:93]
    at com.ibm.ilog.elixir.gantt::GanttChartBase/setItemField()[/data/flex/tools/branches/release-3.5/enterprise/build/product_build/trial_target/installers/enterprise/trial-sources/library/gantt/gantt/src/flex/com/ibm/ilog/elixir/gantt/GanttChartBase.as:1506]
    at com.ibm.ilog.elixir.gantt::GanttChartBase/commitTaskItem()[/data/flex/tools/branches/release-3.5/enterprise/build/product_build/trial_target/installers/enterprise/trial-sources/library/gantt/gantt/src/flex/com/ibm/ilog/elixir/gantt/GanttChartBase.as:1458]
    at com.ibm.ilog.elixir.gantt::TaskChart/commitTaskItem()[/data/flex/tools/branches/release-3.5/enterprise/build/product_build/trial_target/installers/enterprise/trial-sources/library/gantt/gantt/src/flex/com/ibm/ilog/elixir/gantt/TaskChart.as:1250]
    at com.ibm.ilog.elixir.gantt::GanttSheet/commitItem()[/data/flex/tools/branches/release-3.5/enterprise/build/product_build/trial_target/installers/enterprise/trial-sources/library/gantt/gantt/src/flex/com/ibm/ilog/elixir/gantt/GanttSheet.as:10242]
    at com.ibm.ilog.elixir.gantt::GanttSheet/resizeSummaryTask()[/data/flex/tools/branches/release-3.5/enterprise/build/product_build/trial_target/installers/enterprise/trial-sources/library/gantt/gantt/src/flex/com/ibm/ilog/elixir/gantt/GanttSheet.as:10399]
    at com.ibm.ilog.elixir.gantt::GanttSheet/resizeSummaryTasks()[/data/flex/tools/branches/release-3.5/enterprise/build/product_build/trial_target/installers/enterprise/trial-sources/library/gantt/gantt/src/flex/com/ibm/ilog/elixir/gantt/GanttSheet.as:10302]
    at com.ibm.ilog.elixir.gantt::GanttSheet/taskCollection_collectionChangeHandler()[/data/flex/tools/branches/release-3.5/enterprise/build/product_build/trial_target/installers/enterprise/trial-sources/library/gantt/gantt/src/flex/com/ibm/ilog/elixir/gantt/GanttSheet.as:9573]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.collections::HierarchicalCollectionView/nestedCollectionChangeHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\advancedgrids\src\mx\collections\HierarchicalCollectionView.as:1594]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.collections::ListCollectionView/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\collections\ListCollectionView.as:1024]
    at mx.collections::HierarchicalCollectionView/xmlNotification()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\advancedgrids\src\mx\collections\HierarchicalCollectionView.as:1816]
    at Function/<anonymous>()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\utils\XMLNotifier.as:93]
    at com.indven.epm.project.util::CommandsUtil$/movNode()[D:\flash builder workspace\trunk\Sources\FlexSources\src\com\indven\epm\project\util\CommandsUtil.as:346]
    at com.indven.epm.project.util::CommandsUtil$/moveUpNode()[D:\flash builder workspace\trunk\Sources\FlexSources\src\com\indven\epm\project\util\CommandsUtil.as:270]
    at com.indven.epm.project.util::CommandsUtil$/changeNodeHierarchy()[D:\flash builder workspace\trunk\Sources\FlexSources\src\com\indven\epm\project\util\CommandsUtil.as:109]
    at com.indven.epm.project.task.view::TaskDetails/moveUp()[D:\flash builder workspace\trunk\Sources\FlexSources\src\com\indven\epm\project\task\view\TaskDetailsHandler.as:1231]
    at com.indven.epm.project.task.view::TaskDetails/___TaskDetails_Button11_click()[D:\flash builder workspace\trunk\Sources\FlexSources\src\com\indven\epm\project\task\view\TaskDetails.mxml:55]`enter code here`
```

Comment: Nice to know. Do you also have a question?

Comment: can you help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: No really, you'll have to provide more context. All you give us is an error message. All I can see in there is that the error originates in the Elixir Gantt chart component. You may (or may as well not) be looking at a bug in that component.

Comment: Yes, more context, like try to show the relevant code that is executing when the problem happens. But here's a hint to get you started: this type of error is likely to arise when you change the contents of the data provider. And if we look at your stack trace, it looks like you are executing functions like "movNode", "moveUpNode", "changeNodeHierarchy", and "moveUp". I'm guessing you're changing stuff and some other component (the gantt chart) is not expecting it.

Comment: Doh! Why am I commenting on an issue from 6 months ago :(